Nav2 Goal reached far before an end point
I am working on navigation through poses and when providing a path for the robot to follow, it's finishing it far before the end point. What could be a reason for that? In logs there is no error, the last few messages from navigaiton2 are:
[component_container_isolated-1] [WARN] [1728486849.792508548] [BehaviorTreeEngine]: Behavior Tree tick rate 100.00 was exceeded!
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1728486850.173913153] [controller_server]: Reached the goal!
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1728486850.211487116] [bt_navigator]: Goal succeeded

The same is from nav2_simple_commander script, the output is: Goal succeeded!. On the below screen it is clear than the end point is not achieved yet. I am using ROS2 humble with setup for differential drive robot of rectangular shape.

My nav2_simple_commander script is very similar to the exemplary one and below is the nav2 configuration:
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.1 
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_footprint"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.3
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 20.0 #100
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 100
    max_particles: 3000
    min_particles: 600
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.01 
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.01 
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 0.5 #0.5
    update_min_a: 0.05 #0.1
    update_min_d: 0.05 #0.1
    z_hit: 0.9
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.05
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: /lidar/scan
    set_initial_pose: false # Published from script
    always_reset_initial_pose: false
    first_map_only: false
    initial_pose:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      yaw: 0.0

amcl_map_client:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

amcl_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odometry/filtered
    navigators: ["navigate_complete_coverage", "navigate_through_poses", "navigate_to_pose"]
    #default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share nav2_bt_navigator)/behavior_trees/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share navigation)/behavior_trees/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery_if_invalid.xml
    default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share navigation)/behavior_trees/navigate_w_recovery_and_replanning_only_if_path_becomes_invalid.xml
    default_coverage_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share navigation)/behavior_trees/navigate_w_basic_complete_coverage_nav_to_start.xml
    #default_coverage_bt_xml: $(find-pkg-share opennav_coverage_bt)/behavior_trees/navigate_w_basic_complete_coverage.xml
    navigate_through_poses:
      plugin: "backported_bt_navigator/NavigateThroughPosesNavigator"
    navigate_complete_coverage:
      plugin: "opennav_coverage_navigator/CoverageNavigator"
    navigate_to_pose:
      plugin: "backported_bt_navigator/NavigateToPoseNavigator"
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    plugin_lib_names:
      - opennav_compute_complete_coverage_action_bt_node
      - opennav_cancel_complete_coverage_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_get_pose_from_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_in_collision_goals_action_bt_node
    error_code_names: 
      - compute_path_error_code 
      - follow_path_error_code
      - compute_coverage_error_code

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

coverage_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    default_headland_width: 0.3 # 0.3
    robot_width: 0.525
    operation_width: 0.525
    min_turning_radius: 0.0 #0.1
    linear_curv_change: 1000.0
    coordinates_in_cartesian_frame: true
    default_allow_overlap: true
    default_swath_angle_type: "BRUTE_FORCE"
    default_swath_type: "NUMBER"
    default_step_angle: 0.261799 # radians (15 deg)
    default_path_continuity_type: "DISCONTINUOUS"  #DISCONTINUOUS
    default_turn_point_distance: 0.05
    #default_turn_point_distance: 0.15

bt_navigator_navigate_complete_coverage_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True





controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 10.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.5
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    failure_tolerance: 0.3
    progress_checker_plugin: "progress_checker"
    goal_checker_plugins: ["general_goal_checker"] 
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    # Progress checker parameters
    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::PoseProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.1
      required_movement_angle: 0.3
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    
    general_goal_checker:
      stateful: True
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.1
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.05


    # RPP parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_regulated_pure_pursuit_controller::RegulatedPurePursuitController"
      desired_linear_vel: 0.5
      lookahead_dist: 2.0
      min_lookahead_dist: 0.6
      max_lookahead_dist: 2.5
      lookahead_time: 5.0
      rotate_to_heading_angular_vel: 1.8
      use_velocity_scaled_lookahead_dist: true
      min_approach_linear_velocity: 0.05
      approach_velocity_scaling_dist: 0.6
      use_collision_detection: false
      max_allowed_time_to_collision_up_to_carrot: 0.1
      use_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: true
      use_fixed_curvature_lookahead: false
      curvature_lookahead_dist: 0.25
      use_cost_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: false
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_radius: 0.9
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_speed: 0.25
      use_rotate_to_heading: true  # allows to follow coverage path better in sharper turns
      allow_reversing: false
      rotate_to_heading_min_angle: 0.785
      max_angular_accel: 3.2
      #max_robot_pose_search_dist: 10.0
      use_interpolation: true

controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      #robot_radius: 0.42
      footprint: "[ [0.336, 0.273], [0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, 0.273] ]"
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        inflation_radius: 1.0
        cost_scaling_factor: 2.5
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan #proximal_depth distal_depth
        scan:
          topic: /lidar/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 0.5
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
        # proximal_depth:
        #   topic: /camera/depth_registered/points
        #   max_obstacle_height: 0.5
        #   clearing: True
        #   marking: True
        #   data_type: "PointCloud2"
        #   raytrace_max_range: 1.5
        #   raytrace_min_range: 0.0
        #   obstacle_max_range: 1.0
        #   obstacle_min_range: 0.0
        # distal_depth:
        #   topic: /top_camera/depth_registered/points
        #   max_obstacle_height: 0.5
        #   clearing: True
        #   marking: True
        #   data_type: "PointCloud2"
        #   raytrace_max_range: 3.5
        #   raytrace_min_range: 0.0
        #   obstacle_max_range: 3.0
        #   obstacle_min_range: 0.0

      # voxel_layer:
      #   plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
      #   enabled: True
      #   publish_voxel_map: False
      #   origin_z: 0.0
      #   z_resolution: 0.05
      #   z_voxels: 16
      #   max_obstacle_height: 2.0
      #   mark_threshold: 0
      #   observation_sources: upper_depth
      #   upper_depth:
      #     topic: /camera/depth_registered/points
      #     max_obstacle_height: 0.5
      #     clearing: True
      #     marking: True
      #     data_type: "PointCloud2"
      #     raytrace_max_range: 2.5
      #     raytrace_min_range: 0.0
      #     obstacle_max_range: 2.0
      #     obstacle_min_range: 0.0

        # upper_depth:  # no frame set, uses frame from message
        #   topic: camera/depth_registered/points
        #   max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        #   min_obstacle_height: 0.01
        #   obstacle_max_range: 2.5
        #   obstacle_min_range: 0.0
        #   raytrace_max_range: 3.0
        #   raytrace_min_range: 0.0
        #   clearing: true
        #   marking: true
        #   data_type: "PointCloud2"

      # voxel_layer:
      #   plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
      #   enabled: True
      #   publish_voxel_map: True
      #   origin_z: 0.0
      #   z_resolution: 0.05
      #   z_voxels: 16
      #   max_obstacle_height: 2.0
      #   mark_threshold: 0
      #   observation_sources: scan
      #   scan:
      #     topic: /lidar/scan
      #     max_obstacle_height: 2.0
      #     clearing: True
      #     marking: True
      #     data_type: "LaserScan"
      #     raytrace_max_range: 3.0
      #     raytrace_min_range: 0.0
      #     obstacle_max_range: 2.5
      #     obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      #robot_radius: 0.42
      footprint: "[ [0.336, 0.273], [0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, -0.273], [-0.336, 0.273] ]"
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: True
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan #proximal_depth distal_depth
        scan:
          topic: /lidar/scan
          max_obstacle_height: 0.5
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
        # proximal_depth:
        #   topic: /camera/depth_registered/points
        #   max_obstacle_height: 0.5
        #   clearing: True
        #   marking: True
        #   data_type: "PointCloud2"
        #   raytrace_max_range: 1.5
        #   raytrace_min_range: 0.0
        #   obstacle_max_range: 1.0
        #   obstacle_min_range: 0.0
        # distal_depth:
        #   topic: /top_camera/depth_registered/points
        #   max_obstacle_height: 0.5
        #   clearing: True
        #   marking: True
        #   data_type: "PointCloud2"
        #   raytrace_max_range: 3.5
        #   raytrace_min_range: 0.0
        #   obstacle_max_range: 3.0
        #   obstacle_min_range: 0.0

      # voxel_layer:
      #   plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
      #   enabled: True
      #   publish_voxel_map: False
      #   origin_z: 0.0
      #   z_resolution: 0.05
      #   z_voxels: 16
      #   max_obstacle_height: 2.0
      #   mark_threshold: 0
      #   observation_sources: upper_depth
      #   upper_depth:
      #     topic: /camera/depth_registered/points
      #     max_obstacle_height: 0.5
      #     clearing: True
      #     marking: True
      #     data_type: "PointCloud2"
      #     raytrace_max_range: 2.5
      #     raytrace_min_range: 0.0
      #     obstacle_max_range: 2.0
      #     obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: False
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    yaml_filename: "map.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True


planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    planner_plugins: ['GridBased']
    GridBased:
      plugin: 'nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner' # In Iron and older versions, "/" was used instead of "::"
      use_astar: True
      allow_unknown: False
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_final_approach_orientation: False

# planner_server:
#   ros__parameters:
#     expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
#     use_sim_time: True
#     planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
#     GridBased:
#       plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerLattice"
#       tolerance: 0.1                     # tolerance for planning if unable to reach exact pose, in meters
#       lattice_filepath: "$(find-pkg-share navigation)/config/lattice_planner.json" 
#       downsample_costmap: false           # whether or not to downsample the map
#       downsampling_factor: 1              # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
#       allow_unknown: false                # allow traveling in unknown space
#       max_iterations: 1000000             # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
#       max_on_approach_iterations: 1000    # maximum number of iterations to attempt to reach goal once in tolerance
#       max_planning_time: 3.5              # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth, and upsample. Will scale maximum smoothing and upsampling times based on remaining time after planning.
#       cost_travel_multiplier: 2.0         # For 2D: Cost multiplier to apply to search to steer away from high cost areas. Larger values will place in the center of aisles more exactly (if non-`FREE` cost potential field exists) but take slightly longer to compute. To optimize for speed, a value of 1.0 is reasonable. A reasonable tradeoff value is 2.0. A value of 0.0 effective disables steering away from obstacles and acts like a naive binary search A*.
#       angle_quantization_bins: 64         # For Hybrid nodes: Number of angle bins for search, must be 1 for 2D node (no angle search)
#       analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5       # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
#       analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0    # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting (in meters). This should be scaled with minimum turning radius and be no less than 4-5x the minimum radius
#       analytic_expansion_max_cost_override: true
#       minimum_turning_radius: 0.0       # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
#       reverse_penalty: 4.0                # For Reeds-Shepp model: penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
#       change_penalty: 0.05                 # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply if motion is changing directions, must be >= 0
#       non_straight_penalty: 1.05          # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
#       cost_penalty: 2.0                   # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
#       retrospective_penalty: 0.015        # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: penalty to prefer later maneuvers before earlier along the path. Saves search time since earlier nodes are not expanded until it is necessary. Must be >= 0.0 and <= 1.0
#       rotation_penalty: 0.5              # For Lattice node: Penalty to apply only to pure rotate in place commands when using minimum control sets containing rotate in place primitives. This should always be set sufficiently high to weight against this action unless strictly necessary for obstacle avoidance or there may be frequent discontinuities in the plan where it requests the robot to rotate in place to short-cut an otherwise smooth path for marginal path distance savings.
#       lookup_table_size: 20.0               # For Hybrid nodes: Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
#       cache_obstacle_heuristic: true      # For Hybrid nodes: Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.  
#       allow_reverse_expansion: false      # For Lattice nodes: Whether to expand state lattice graph in forward primitives or reverse as well, will double the branching factor at each step.   
#       smooth_path: true                   # For Lattice/Hybrid nodes: Whether or not to smooth the path, always true for 2D nodes.
#       smoother:
#         max_iterations: 1000
#         w_smooth: 0.3
#         w_data: 0.2
#         tolerance: 1.0e-10
#         do_refinement: true               # Whether to recursively run the smoother 3 times on the results from prior runs to refine the results further

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 200
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"   
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

  
velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.5, 0.0, 2.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.5, 0.0, -2.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 5.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -5.2]
    odom_topic: "/odometry/filtered"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: global_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: global_costmap/published_footprint
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      do_refinement: True

